# URL encription in WCF/HTML

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, wcf

How can we encrpt a URL.(Let me explain a scenario: we are having a WCF service which return a URL to the client, which renders that in HTML page. )

Can We encrpt the URL so that end users wont directly use it(by hitting on it directly)

Comment: And what would you like to accomplish with that? it wouldn't stop any one from actually using the unencrypted url and seeing that you'd have to descrypt before you could do NS lookup getting the actual URL would be extremely simple. If you just dont what it to be a link in a web page just include it as plain text and not a link

Comment: Sorry, i think i was not able to explain the problem completely. Here , what exactly we need to accomplish is to prevent Fraud(the url which we give as O/p frm wcf we dnt need that to be used by someone other than client window.), by that i mean I dnt want that URL to be visible/Floated or to be copy pasted in browser and HItted.

Comment: If you don't want people using your URL in a fraudulent way make sure your server requires authentication. Hiding the URL in transit will not help for long, especially if you'll be opening it in an embedded browser. Anyone can sniff the network traffic and see exactly what "HTTP GET" is sent and go from there. They could even use Fiddler to get the URL. Any half-competent HTML hacker that might try copy-pasting your URL knows about Fiddler.

Answer (score 1):

You can't hide a service by encrypting the URL. You'll need to handle the access at an infrastructure level and you basically have few options for that

- Firewall the service so that only parties with known ips can call it. IPs can be spoofed so this is not bullet proof but can serve as a barrier
- use 2 way SSL
- use authentication and authorization

to be able to use a URL you need to be able to resolve the URL to an IP to be able to do that you need to be able to request the IP from a DNS server which in turn needs to know the real URL. So you can't ask the DNS server for the IP of an encrypted URL and even if you could you would gain anything because what you really wish to protect is the IP not the URL and if hide the IP from the outside world (evil and benign) you'd not be able to communicate with any one

Answer (score 0):

No, No, No,No, No, No, this is not possible, a URL is public, that's the whole point its an address to somewhere you want people to be able to get to.

Comment: Toby its like, the url is what we sell and we dont want it to be used except for the Client who created it.We dont want the url to be created and circulated to be used by others

Comment: It doesn't matter what you sell a url is always public, you need a differnt solution